# If Mordechai knew he would endanger the whole nation would he bow to Haman?

Tags: halacha-theory, purim, pikuachnefesh-danger-life, haman, mordechai

If I understand the plot correctly, the story of Haman's hatred to Mordechai and the whole Jewish people started with Mordechai disobeying the king's laws.

First, did Mordechai (as a prophet) know he endangers the whole nation?

Second, If Mordechai knew he would endanger the whole nation would he still not bow to Haman?

Third, what does the Halacha says about such behavior - is one really forbidden **to pretend to bow** to an official even if he puts his whole nation in a life-threatening situation?

Comment: Mordechai clearly had full faith that the Jews would be saved in fact he told Ester that if she did not marry achashveirosh there would be saviour from elsewhere. also we are obligated to give our lives rather than worship avoda zoro cheshbonos don't come into question. its a bit like don't overpopulate the world because there might not be enough food. Have some Emuna and Bitachon

Comment: I've heard a pshat that Hashem took away mordechai's bitachon when he bowed to Haman.

Comment: @user15464 If you knew that failing Hitler into Academy of Fine Arts in Vienna would light the WW2 and cause 6M Jews to die - would you do that with your Emunah and Bitachon?